# How to get histogram data object from matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Lets say I have a matrix `x=[ 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 ]`. To look at its histogram, I can do `h=hist(x).`

Now, h with retrieve a matrix consisting only the number of occurrences and does not store the original value to which it occurred.

What I want is something like a function which takes a value from `x` and returns number of occurrences of it. Having said that, what one thing `histeq` does should we admire is, it automatically scales nearest values according!

How should solve this issue? How exactly people do it?

My reason of interest is in images:

Lets say I have an image. I want to find all number of occurrences of a chrominance value of image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really shure what you are looking for, but if you ant to use hist to count the number of occurences, use:

```
[h,c]=hist(x,sort(unique(x)))
```

Otherwise hist uses ranges defined by centers. The second output argument returns the corresponding number.

Comment: +1 I was just typing the same :-) And I agree, the question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

`hist` has a second return value that will be the bin centers `xc` corresponding to the counts `n` returned in form of the first return value: `[n, xc] = hist(x)`. You should have a careful look at the reference which describes a large number of optional arguments that control the behavior of `hist`. However, `hist` is way too mighty for your specific problem.

To simply count the number of occurrences of a specific value, you could simply use something like `sum(x(:) == 42)`. The colon operator will linearize your image matrix, the equals operator will yield a list of boolean values with 1 for each element of `x` that was 42, and thus `sum` will yield the total number of these occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `hist` / `histc` is to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
n = unique(x(:)).'; %'// values contained in x. x can have any number of dims
y = sum(bsxfun(@eq, x(:), n)); %// count for each value
```